# How to read user input from Radio Button in JavaFX into xml file

Tags: java, xml, javafx, javafx-8

I made application for selling internet packages in JavaFX that looks like this. 
[image]

So when user click save button this application is saving all of his data in XML file so I did marshalling

```
@FXML
private void saveInternetPaketxml() throws JAXBException{
    if(internetPaket.isValid()){

        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        internetPaket.InternetPaket internetPaket = objectFactory.createInternetPaket();

        internetPaket.setFirstName(firstName.getText());
        internetPaket.setLastName(lastName.getText());
        internetPaket.setAddress(address.getText());
        internetPaket.setBrzina(brzina.getSelectedToggle().toString());
        internetPaket.setProtok(protok.getSelectedToggle().toString());
        internetPaket.setTrajanjeUgovora(trajanjeUgovora.getToggles().toString());

        JAXBContext jaxbc =JAXBContext.newInstance("internetPaket");
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(internetPaket, new File("out.xml"));
```

but my output in XML file looks like this
[image]

and i need it to look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<internetPaket>
    <firstName>john</firstName>
    <lastName>mayers</lastName>
    <address>ddd</address>
    <brzina>5Mbt</brzina>
    <protok>10GB</protok>
    <trajanjeUgovora>1 Godina</trajanjeUgovora>
</internetPaket>
```

I need help because I'm very new to this. I don't know what to write instead of this:

```
internetPaket.setBrzina(brzina.getSelectedToggle().toString());
        internetPaket.setProtok(protok.getSelectedToggle().toString());
        internetPaket.setTrajanjeUgovora(trajanjeUgovora.getToggles().toString());
```

to get from my Radio Button and Toggle Button right output also I need advice how to keep every "sale" in my XML file because now every time i insert new user only his data is in XML file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[getSelectedToggle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/RadioButton.html) returns you an instance of toggled radio button. Do not call `toString`! Call `getText` instead and there you go.

Sidenote:

1) You always want to name your variables, classes, methods in english.

2) I don't see a point of using `ToggleButton's` in "Izaberi trajanje ugovora". You can use `RadioButton's` there too.

Comment: Now when I write  internetPaket.setBrzina(brzina.getSelectedToggle().getText()); it says can not find symbol it does not work, also thank you for sidenot I know I should write on english but since I'm beginner it is easier for me.

Comment: @Leona `((RadioButton)brzina.getSelectedToggle()).getText()`

Comment: When I write internetPaket.setBrzina((RadioButton)brzina.getSelectedToggle()).getText();       it says incompatible types: RadioButton can not be converted to String

Comment: Come on, think just a little: `internetPaket.setBrzina(((RadioButton)brzina.getSelectedToggle()).getText());`